# C++ template: cannot match the last template in variadic class template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic, partial-ordering

I'm learning C++11 variadic template and created a template struct to calculate the max number of a given list and tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <int a, int b, int... cs>
struct max: std::integral_constant<int, (a>b? max<a, cs...>::value: max<b, cs...>::value)> {};
template <int a, int b>
struct max<a, b>: std::integral_constant<int, (a>b? max<a>::value: max<b>::value)> {};
template <int a>
struct max<a>: std::integral_constant<int, a> {};

int main() {
  std::cout << max<2,1,5,7>::value << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

but g++ complains:

```
test.cc:7:58: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be at least 2)
 struct max<a, b>: std::integral_constant<int, (a>b? max<a>::value : max<b>::value)> {};

test.cc:9:13: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be at least 2)
 struct max<a>: std::integral_constant<int, a> {};
```

I can make it run by adding a simple declaration ahead:

```
template <int...>
struct max;
```

and change the first template above to:

```
template <int a, int b, int... cs>
struct max<a, b, cs...>: ...
```

I referred to cppreference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization#Partial_ordering
but I cannot find any useful explanation for my case.

The problem may come from the last template (`max<a>`) with only one template parameter, which is not a specialized version of the primary one.

So my question is:

Why `max<a>` cannot be matched? Is there any rules or standards dealing with this?

=================================================================

okay, I found the C++ standards (Document No. N4659) that says:

> [ Note: Partial specializations of class templates are found by
>   looking up the primary class template and **then considering** all partial
>   specializations of that template. If a using-declaration names a class
>   template, partial specializations introduced after the
>   using-declaration are effectively visible because the primary template
>   is visible (17.5.5). — end note ]

So I think any partial specialized template that does not specialize from the base/primary one is considered to be an error, even though sometimes we can generate some non-specialized forms of expression from normal ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you define a class template as:

```
template <int a, int b, int... cs> struct max { ... };
```

The following is a valid specialization.

```
template <int a, int b> struct max<a, b> { ... };
```

However, the following is not.

```
template <int a> struct max<a> { ... };
```

since the base class template requires at least two template parameters.

Comment: So does the standard require the following partial spec template must be a specialized version of the primary one?

Comment: @bigtit, I didn't get your drift. Please elaborate.

Comment: you said `since the base class template requires at least two template parameters.` so I assume that the c++ standard force all the templates after the base one to be a specialized version of it, as in this case `max<a>` is not a more specialized version of the base template?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting that error is that every invocation of the template must first match the base template, and specialization only kicks in after that.

Your base template should match any number of arguments, and have no implementation (since `max<>::value` makes no sense), and have a single variadic argument, with all your other classes be specialization of that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<int... cs>
struct max;

template <int a, int b, int... cs>
struct max<a, b, cs...>: std::integral_constant<int, (a>b? max<a, cs...>::value: max<b, cs...>::value)> {};
template <int a, int b>
struct max<a, b>: std::integral_constant<int, (a>b? max<a>::value: max<b>::value)> {};
template <int a>
struct max<a>: std::integral_constant<int, a> {};

int main() {
  std::cout << max<2,1,5,7>::value << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually I tried other writings with the primary template having implementations and they worked fine. So I assume what you mean 'should' here is a convention?

Comment: @bigint, Oh, yes, the primary template can have an implementation. It's just that in your case, `max<>::value` makes no sense whatsoever, so you should leave it undefined. I've amended the answer to clarify.

Comment: @Frank One can argue that `max<>::value` should be `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`. Otherwise, the base-template should require at least one template-argument.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but why not simply...

```
template <int a, int... bs>
struct max : std::integral_constant<int,
   (a > max<bs...>::value ? a : max<bs...>::value)> {};

template <int a>
struct max<a> : std::integral_constant<int, a> {};
```

...?

Comment: why dont you make it an answer? It doesnt answer the question literally, but thats what OP was actually after, i guess

Comment: @user463035818 I am not sure about this, since OP asked for rules. He even knew how to make his solution work by adding another version of primary template.

Comment: oh you are right. I misread the question, was already wondering why top answers does not mention how to fix it ;)